# Does the class lock have the same effect if I use a static variable in this class as a lock in Java?

Tags: java

Example:

```
class A {
    public static Integer age;
}

// Approach 1:
class Exe1 {
    public void exec() {
        synchronized(A.class) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}

// Approach 2
public class Exec2 {
    public void exec() {
        synchronized(A.age) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Does the code in approach 2 behave the same way as approach 1?

I mean, do these two approaches have the same effect to control the order of the execution of the code?

Comment: Approach 2 does not lock on a variable.  It locks on the object that is the (current) *value* of the variable.   That is a different object to `A.class` ... so the answer is No.

Answer (score 5):

No, it does not.

The `synchronize(A.class)` block is controlled by the `Class<A>` instance of the `A` class, which always exists and is always the same instance<sup>1</sup>. So every execution of `Exe1.exec()` is locked/synchronized by this same instance.

The `synchronize(A.age)` block however is controlled by the current instance which is currently in the static field `A.age`. It can be change by assigning a different instance to `A.age` like `A.age = Integer.valueOf(42);`. After that every execution of `Exe2.exec()` is controlled by **that** `Integer` object, independently of other currently locked executions of `Exe2.exec()`. Additionally the `A.age` can be `null`, which means you will get an exception when you run into `synchronize(null) {...}`.

---

<sup>1</sup>) The JLS makes no requirement that the `.class` expression (see [15.8.2. Class Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)) always returns the same instance, see [JLS - 12.2. Loading of Classes and Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2):

> Well-behaved class loaders maintain these properties:
>
> - Given the same name, a good class loader should always return the same class object.